# "llegal group reference" when running Google maven replacer plugin

Tags: maven, substitution, maven-replacer-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3.  I have this plugin in my pom.xml file …

```
                    <!-- creates a test database script from the properties file -->
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3</version>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <phase>compile</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>replace</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <configuration>
                                    <file>src/test/resources/META-INF/db-test-data.sql.templ</file>
                                    <outputFile>target/test-classes/db-test-data.sql</outputFile>
                                    <tokenValueMap>src/test/resources/test.properties</tokenValueMap>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

I notice that when my “test.properties” file contains a property like so

```
test.sample.school2.name=Middle $ample Elementary #2
```

I get the below error when the plugin executes …

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.3:replace (default) on project core: Illegal group reference -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The problem is with the “$” in the replaced value.  If I remove it, everything is fine.  However, sometimes the replaced value will have a “$”.  Is there a way to configure the plugin to accept the “$”, or barring that, is there an equivalent plugin I can use that will achieve the same thing as above?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the `$` token (and other such regex symbols):

```
test.sample.school2.name=Middle \$ample Elementary #2
```

Just so you know, the `$`  character is used to denote the matching groups in during the replacement in regex (hence the error message).

This has nothing to do with the escaping required on the keys in a property file when loading of course, but this plugin probably does a `replaceAll` for regex support.

Quoting its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29),

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use
>   `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

but apparently, the `replacer` plugin's code doesn't use the `quoteReplacement` to escape an arbitrary replacement string (in this case, it's the string: `"Middle $ample Elementary #2"`), so you must escape it yourself.

---

If you don't intend to use regex matching/replacements at all, you could set the `regex` flag to `false` in the plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <file>src/test/resources/META-INF/db-test-data.sql.templ</file>
  <outputFile>target/test-classes/db-test-data.sql</outputFile>
  <tokenValueMap>src/test/resources/test.properties</tokenValueMap>
  <regex>false</regex>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to do that in the properties file itself.  It is not intuitive and will cause problems for other folks who come in down the line and are not familiar with the finicky plugin.  I want a straight search and replace.

Comment: @DaveA, if you don't intend to use the regex matching/replacement at all, you could simply turn it off by setting the `regex` flag in the plugin's config to `false`. I've updated my answer with this suggestion.